# TypeError: jest.mock is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am getting an error as

`TypeError: jest.mock is not a function` - while i do my testing here. any one help me to sort this?

[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-api-test-41r5v?file=/src/App.spec.tsx)

My test code :

```
import { render, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import { screen } from "@testing-library/dom";
import { mocked } from "ts-jest/utils";
import App from "./App";
import { getUsers } from "./userService";
//import apiForUserName from "../src/__mocks__/API";
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
jest.mock("./userService");
const mockGetUsers = mocked(getUsers, true);

describe("get username using promise", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockGetUsers.mockClear();
  });
  beforeEach(async () => {
    render(<App baseURL={url} />);
    await waitFor(() => expect(mockGetUsers).toHaveBeenCalled());
  });
  it("should call getUsers once", async () => {
    render(<App baseURL={url} />);
    await waitFor(() => expect(mockGetUsers).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
  });
  it("should render the username", async () => {
    const name = "John";
    mockGetUsers.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.resolve({ username: name })
    );
    render(<App baseURL={url} />);
    expect(screen.queryByText(/username/)).toBeNull();
    expect(await screen.findByText(/name/)).toBeInTheDocument();
    screen.debug();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeSandbox does **NOT** support jest manually mocks, snapshot saving, jest config, and code coverage yet. see [issue#513](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/513)